# EntityTooLarge when uploading multipart object with parts smaller than 5GB to AWS S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Although I am very aware that **files bigger than 5GB should be uploaded using the multipart upload API**, I am still getting the `EntityTooLarge - Your proposed upload exceeds the maximum allowed size` error message when trying to upload *individual parts* smaller than 5GB. I even tried parts as small as 10MB, but to no avail.

This is the way I am calling it (I'm using the [Node.js AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#uploadPart-property)):

```js
s3.uploadPart({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Body: fs.createReadStream(fullFilePath, { start: start, end: end }),
    ContentMD5: md5,
    UploadId: uploadId,
    PartNumber: partNumber,
}, (error, data) => error ? console.error(error) : console.info(data));
```

I am using [`fs.createReadStream()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) with the `start` and `end` options so I can slice the file and send it in smaller chunks. I tested that stream and it's really slicing the file, so I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of trial-and-error, I found out that I had to specify a `ContentLength` option as well:

```js
s3.uploadPart({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
    Body: fs.createReadStream(fullFilePath, { start: start, end: end }),
    ContentLength: bodySize,
    ContentMD5: md5,
    UploadId: uploadId,
    PartNumber: partNumber,
}, (error, data) => error ? console.error(error) : console.info(data));
```

Where `bodySize` is just `end - start + 1`, i.e., the size of the slice being uploaded.

It kinda makes sense to pass it since the API has no way of knowing the size of the stream chunk I'm providing.

Comment: I saw your original question, and I was wondering how (or if!) "slicing a file with fs.createReadStream() ... using start and end options" could possibly work.  The answer is "it does work" ... with the caveat that you need to explicitly specify `ContentLength:`.  Please be sure to "Accept" your answer!